# Catching exceptions for specific base members during construction

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm aware, given a class `foo` with a base class `base` that I can write

```
foo(/*real code has parameters here*/) try : 
   base(), /*real code has parameters here*/
   anotherMember(someFunction(/*some parameters here*/))
{
} catch (...){
}
```

but is there a syntax I can use to put the `try` `catch` block around just `anotherMember` as opposed to the entire base member list and constructor body?

(note that `anotherMember` is a `const` type so needs to be in the initialiser list)

Comment: Can you modify the classes of the members? Couldn't you just simply throw a distinct exception type from each constructor and catch the one you want? Or perhaps have all of them (those that *may* throw) throw a custom exception with some data that identifies the offending type and use that to do what you want.

Comment: I smell X-Y problem. WHY do you want to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hum. My boss is accusing me of being "fundamentally illogical".

Comment: -1, yes you are. Either (i) `anotherMember` has to be constructed or (ii) the whole construction fails. You can't have a bit of either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing that doesn't quite make sense but as `anotherMember` initialises from a function you could put `try..catch` in that function. I'm assuming it has a copy-constructor that doesn't throw and one that might throw that takes parameters and your `someFunction` invokes that one.

What do you want to do if `anotherMember` fails to construct properly?

Your obvious alternative is to wrap the `anotherMember` in some kind of smart-pointer, possibly making it "nullable" if it failed to initialise. If you created your own special object it would contain the message of the exception thrown .

```
struct AnotherTypeWrapper
{
    std::unique_ptr< AnotherType > ptr;
    std::string errorMsg;

    AnotherTypeWrapper( Args&& args... ) // ok probably not variadic
    {
       try
       {
          ptr.reset( new AnotherType( std::forward(args) ) ); // or whatever the syntax
       }
       catch( std::exception const& err )
       {
          errorMsg = err.what();
       }
    }
};
```

Something like that.